# Unable to make ShouldSerialize pattern work with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

I have been able to use ShouldSerialize*Property* pattern with `XmlSerializer` to ignore a property of type `ICollection<>`. Below is the sample code. It works if I use `XmlIgnore` on `ListOfTestClassB` property but I want to achieve the same functionality utilizing `ShouldSerialize` pattern. If I run the code below I get the 'System.InvalidOperationException' saying:

> Cannot serialize member ConsoleApplication3.TestClassA.ListOfTestClassB of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[ConsoleApplication3.TestClassB, ConsoleApplication3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

Can anyone highlight what am I missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
   [Serializable]
   public class TestClassA
   {
      public int A { get; set; }
      public int B { get; set; }
      public string C { get; set; }
      public TestClassB TestClass { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<TestClassB> ListOfTestClassB { get; set; }

      public bool ShouldSerializeListOfTestClassB()
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   [Serializable]
   public class TestClassB 
   {
      public int Int32 { get; set; }
      public string String { get; set; }
   }


   class Program
   {
      static object GetObject()
      {
         return new TestClassA { A = 1, B = 2, C = "test class a", TestClass = new TestClassB { Int32 = 11, String = "test class b"} };
      }
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         var result = new StringBuilder();
         var entity = GetObject();
         var ser = new XmlSerializer(entity.GetType());

         var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true };

         using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            // make a copy of the entity - we do not want to serialize ZIP file !
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, entity);
            stream.Position = 0;
            entity = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
         }

         // serialize object
         ser.Serialize(XmlWriter.Create(result, settings), entity);

         Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where the check happens:  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/Models.cs,249.

As you can see, it doesn't call the `ShouldSerialize*` method until after it's already identified fields/properties to serialize.  So, your `ListOfTestClassB` has to be serializable, *or* it must be decorated with `[XmlIgnore]`.  In order to be serializable your property must be of a concrete type that has the `[Serializable]` attribute applied.

There's a workaround if you can't modify the class.  One of the overloads of the `XmlSerializer.Serialize(...)` method accepts an *overrides* object.  I've created a simple example below:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public IList<int> Numbers { get; set; }
    public string TheNumber { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var attributes = new XmlAttributes
        {
            XmlIgnore = true
        };
        var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        overrides.Add(typeof(Foo), "Numbers", attributes);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo), overrides);

        // the rest of this is for demo purposes.  
        // the code above is whats important
        //
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(ms, new Foo() { TheNumber = "5" });    
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

    }

}
```

This generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TheNumber>5</TheNumber>
</Foo>
```

As you can see, I'm dynamically adding the `XmlIgnore` attribute to my `Numbers` element, and the serializer consequently ignores it.  :)  You should have no trouble adapting this to your own code.

**Note:** As noted by [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc), it's important to cache this serializer and re-use it, otherwise you're going to have a lot of memory leaks.  You can keep a static reference to it, or use a hashtable to store different serializers for different types.

> To increase performance, the XML serialization infrastructure dynamically generates assemblies to serialize and deserialize specified types. The infrastructure finds and reuses those assemblies. This behavior occurs only when using the following constructors:

```
XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type)
XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(Type, String)
```

> If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable, as shown in the following example.

Comment: That serializer needs to be cached, e.g. in a static hash table, to avoid a severe memory leak.  See [XmlSerializer Class: Dynamically Generated Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @dbc.  I've edited my answer to bring attention to that.

Comment: Thanks @Amy this looks promising. I came across the use of XmlAttributedOverride but ShouldSerialize patter appeared to be an easy implementation and gives a bit more control but apparently I can't use that. I will use your suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `XmlIgnore`, then it will not care about that property at all.  If you use `ShouldSerialize`, it doesn't know until runtime whether it should serialize that type, so it must be able to.  In this case, the type you're trying to serialize must be a concrete class.  Try using `List<TestClassB>`.

Comment: I don't have control over the class. I coded this sample to post here. TestClassA is a sample of what was generated by EF6 database first approach. The issue is that interfaces are not serializable and thus an exception is thrown. Is there any workaround I can use in this scenario? I just simply want to be able to ignore this ICollection<> property at runtime.

Comment: You don't have any control over the class, but you can add a `ShouldSerialize*` method to it?  I'm confused.

Comment: @shigarr See Amy's comment

Comment: @Amy I was thinking to use partial class to add that functionality.